# Оболочка над Get

Tags: sql, golang

В golang в библиотеке sqlx есть функция Get, выглядит она так

```
func (db *DB) Get(dest interface{}, query string, args ...interface{}) error {
    return Get(db, dest, query, args...)
}
```

Я пытаюсь написать оболочку над этим Get:

```
 func (i database) getDate(query string, args ...interface{}) {
    var value sql.NullString
    i.connection.DB.Unsafe().Get(&value, query, args...)
}
```

В подаю в функцию запрос типа `SELECT MAX(?) FROM ? WHERE pointofcontrol = ? AND commandType = 8 OR commandType = 4` и аргументы для запроса, но получаю ошибку

> Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near '? WHERE pointofcontrol = ? AND commandType = 8 OR
>   commandType = 4' at line 1

Comment: Он говорит, что нельзя `FROM ?`. На ум приходит `fmt.Sptrintf`, только не забудьте защитится от SQL-инъекций. Может быть есть способ с `CONCAT('SELECT MAX(?) FROM ', ?, ' WHERE blah')`, но я не уверен.

Comment: Sprintf я сейчас использую но посоветовали делать через placeholders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто, так как я хочу работать не будет
http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/

Использование bindvars для параметризации имен столбцов или таблиц не будет работать:

```
// doesn't work
db.Query("SELECT * FROM ?", "mytable")

// also doesn't work
db.Query("SELECT ?, ? FROM people", "name", "location")
```